# Displaying YouTube JSON Data in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, listview

I'm making an application to display videos from a channel. At the moment, I'm working on displaying the titles of the videos in a ListView. Whenever I start the activity VideoPlay, the application crashes. What's wrong with my code?

## VideoPlay

Code:

```
package com.aer.illbehonest;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class VideoPlay extends Activity {   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_play);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videolist);
        String[] values = null;

        try {
            VideoData.getTitle(values);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
}
```

## VideoData

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class VideoData {
    public static String[] getTitle(String[] title) throws IOException {
            URL jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/illbehonest/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
            URLConnection jc = jsonURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = jc.getInputStream();
            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);

            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

            JSONObject jdata = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray jentry = jdata.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int entryNumber = 0; entryNumber<=25; entryNumber++){
                    JSONObject entry = jentry.getJSONObject(entryNumber);
                    String[] jtitle = {entry.getString("title")};
                    title = jtitle;
            }
            return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the error or stack trace for the crash? Also you are doing network IO on the main thread, the app will be closed with if it takes any time at all to complete. You need to make the list population asynchronous and move it off the main thread

Comment: Have you set permissions for internet usage?

Comment: I have set permissions for internet usage.

Comment: I am a beginner, so @hardillb can you show me what you mean? Do I need to move it outsid onCreate() or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make the network calls.

There are is a ListView example here:
http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html